# How to create a view that can have multiple views and switch between them using mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find out how this website home page scrolling works https://ghagency.com/

I have tried to search a lot for this functionality but i was not able to *succeed*.

Can you help me code this using `HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT` like what are the tools/hooks required to achieve it?

Please bare with my question i am relatively new to web development field.

Comment: All such sites are called: "Single page site". Just let me remember which sub-type from that is your site...

Comment: i am trying to replicate the first section where scrolling on the section will snap to a different view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally found the correct name. "[Single page site scroll effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=single%20page%20website%20scroll%20effect)" - this is what you need to ask for Google.

Here are 10 ready-to-use templates for your ideas: [click](https://www.cssscript.com/tag/one-page-scroll/) (you can start with that).

For example the second option from previous link looks similar to your site: [click](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/horizontal-vertical-one-page-slider/).